# Email tracking in Gmail using Image Tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gmail

I am using a mail tracking using an image . On compose mail I am attaching a one url to the mail and when user open that mail then request send to my server and i am storing the value, but problem is 
when i want to try to get the ip address and platform then it always return a google ip address because image src is change into the link and my api is call throw the gmail proxy server.

HERE IS MY ORIGINAL URL:

```
<img src="http://************************/api/v2/gmail/track/ViHIHeHbFkshUMhiT3S5loUH_K2_jJly/devider.jpg/localStorage.getItem('arcade_user')" alt="trackable" width="0" height="0" class="CToWUd">
```

HERE IS URL WHICH GMAIL CREATE:

```
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Ly9DoZ8swM7fEWQ0b9BGmVR27LpW_zVYHhBe0MHmeqWr6UG_f7hFdAAp4bOQ1MqV0oyBKGfldxd-CidjfbvHgDT20SbXc05fedZAWSFEWWdR2PNWTtGfoYiRwoveqmbJ8h0fV2-JS0fYvgMMtJS0TCEGqrd_JaCKDAvHN-8NUeHXZ-M1OGPyg5lywmIW0hHqBksZAVM3J2EbvHoRVGE=s0-d-e1-ft#http://*********************/api/v2/gmail/track/ViHIHeHbFkshUMhiT3S5loUH_K2_jJly/devider.jpg/localStorage.getItem('arcade_user')" alt="trackable" width="0" height="0" class="CToWUd">
```

How could I get the actual user ip address ??

I am using a `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for getting the ip address.

Kindly help me as soon as possible, if you have any idea or comments on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What? You should get my IP when I open my email? Why would I want that?

Answer (score 4):

## Simpy, you can't!

It is because google stores attached images on its own servers and then display them in email clients from their own storage.

There is no way how to workaround this. Live with this.

[Read this article to understand.](https://blog.filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-this-means-for-you/)

Comment: And one of the reasons Google does this, is to block what the OP is trying to do.